# Variable from one function in other function

Tags: php, mysqli

i have function connect()

```
function connect(){
    $host = '';
    $name = '';
    $pass = '';
    $port = '';
    $db = '';
    $con = mysqli_connect($host,$name,$pass,$db,$port) or die (mysqli_connect_error());
    return $con;
}
```

And i have function check_exists

```
function check_exists($username){
    $num = mysqli_num_rows(mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM `accounts` WHERE `user` = '$username'"));
    return $num;
}
```

but check_exists don`t know what variable $con is. How can i make that check_exists will know what $con is?

Comment: Well essentially, every time you call the `connect` function, you'll get a new `$con` object. `mysqli_num_rows(mysqli_query(connect(),"SELECT...` However it might be better to call this function once and store the connection object outside of the function scope so that more functions can use it.

Answer (score 4):

you can pass the `$con` to the function like

```
 $con =  connect();
 check_exists($username,$con);

function check_exists($username,$con){
        $num = mysqli_num_rows(mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM `accounts` WHERE `user` = '$username'"));
        return $num;
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

Well for one you could make the `$conn` variable globic or you can get it but calling the connect function `$conn = $this.connect();` in your check_username method